# Span an apsrtable table across two columns

Tags: r, latex, sweave

How do I get `apsrtable` table to generate a multi-column table from an R `data.frame` that spans two columns, i.e.

```
\begin{table*}
...
\end{table*}
```

instead of

```
\begin{table}
...
\end{table}
```

As it is, I have to manually edit that part every time I regenerate the Rnw file, otherwise my wide tables don't fit inside a single column (they overlap with text).

I didn't find any such option in the package's help page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `float` argument to manually specify the environment:

```
apsrtable(..., float='table*')
```